# Using regex in VBA necessary to enable MS VBScript Regular Expression 5.5 in each application using the accdb file

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access

I am using regular expressions in my access vba code to check if a string contains a pattern. I enabled the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5" in `Tools -> References`.

In the vba module I am then using the following code (not runnable). I would like to know if it is necessary to enable the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5 in each Access application on different computers to be able use the vba code or if it is automatically loaded, once the vba uses it. Is there a way to make sure it is loaded automatically?

```
Dim regex As Object
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

With regex
    .Pattern = "^[A-Z]{2}"
End With
```

Comment: 1) Importing a reference is not per computer; it's per file. As long as you're using the same file (not copying the code), you should be fine. 2) If you're using `CreateObject` (AKA, late binding), you don't really need the reference. You only need the reference if you use early binding (e.g., `Dim regex As New RegExp` or `Set regex = New RegExp`).

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it, didn't know that importing a reference is per file.